# Browser started under selenium doesn't use addons

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, user-profile

I'm using python+selenium, with profile that has addons.
On startup it shows them all momentarily, but then they are concealed. They exist, they are not disabled, but invisible and don't work. I can disable and enable it, then it appears on the taskbar and is functional.
[image: screenshot]

When invoking firefox manually with the profile, it works.

Here's what printed to the log.

```
1596129664500   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileO34n0s"
JavaScript error: resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionStore.jsm, line 1325: uncaught exception: 2147746065
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/ExtensionContent.jsm, line 554: TypeError: Argument 1 of PrecompiledScript.executeInGlobal is not an object.
1596129672037   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 41285
1596129672136   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript error: undefined, line 14: Error: An unexpected error occurred
JavaScript error: moz-extension://45aaa1ae-14fe-4a8f-841d-6a9416fd5d09/lib/picture_in_picture_overrides.js, line 15: Error: Incorrect argument types for pictureInPictureParent.setOverrides.
1596129683512   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 41285
```

Can it be because of these errors?

The code itself is of no interest at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path='./profile'

opts=Options()
opts.profile=profile_path
driver=Firefox(options=opts)

breakpoint()
```

Versions are probably more important:

- Mozilla Firefox 68.9.0esr
- geckodriver 0.26.0 (e9783a644016 2019-10-10
  13:38 +0000)

I'm creating an empty directory, then running firefox --new-instance --profile ./profile, then installing addon manually into the profile. But here there is that [profile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eFzlVMpj8-sxvD2Q4VNJrsAUhZnuBzs5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please provide what code sample you have written till now so that people can help you.

Comment: @Pythonologist, yep, moment, will make a bare minimum.

Comment: Can you please provide your profile, or at the very least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: @alexisdevarennes, well, it was fresh one with one addon manually installed, but I'll try to send one tomorrow.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes I've added a link to a profile. But I still think that it's something about some settings, I just don't know which. OS-wide or something about browser. I was trying to remember, but I think I never used profiles with addons with selenium before, so cannot say whether it worked on my system at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your profile there is a file: `prefs.js` which contains a line `user_pref("extensions.lastAppBuildId", "20200707180101");` this line might be at fault for the disabled addons. You could therefore test to decrease this number by 1 or remove the whole line (untested).

```
profile.set_preference("extensions.lastAppBuildId", "<apppID> -1 ")
```

Full example code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
path = '%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\azk4wioue.default' #path to your profile
profile = FirefoxProfile(path) 
profile.set_preference("extensions.lastAppBuildId", "<apppID> -1 ")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Example to use an existing firefox profile:

```
# go to the the following folder %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
# there the firefox profiles should be stored, the default one ending with .default
# now provide the profile to the driver like this:
profile = FirefoxProfile('%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\azk4wioue.default') 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Alternatively install the addon clean on each run through a temporary profile.

```
# go to https://addons.mozilla.org and search for the plugin you want, e.g.:https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/
# rightclick on the button "add to firefox"
# download the target file to a folder of your choice

# then include the addon like this:
driver.install_addon('/Users/someuser/app/extension.xpi', temporary=True)
```

Alternatively 2, you can try setting the extension this way:

```
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension='/Users/someuser/app/extension.xpi')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

If the addons are there after loading the profile but disabled, you can also try this:

```
def newTab(fx, url="about:blank"):
    wnd = fx.execute(selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.Command.NEW_WINDOW)
    handle = wnd["value"]["handle"]
    fx.switch_to.window(handle)
    fx.get(url) # changes handle
    return fx.current_window_handle

def retoggleAllTheAddons(fx):
    initialHandlesCount = len(fx.window_handles)
    addonsTabHandle = newTab(fx, "about:addons")
    fx.execute_script("""
        let hb = document.getElementById("html-view-browser");
        let al = hb.contentWindow.window.document.getElementsByTagName("addon-list")[0];
        let cards = al.getElementsByTagName("addon-card");
        for(let card of cards){
            card.addon.disable();
            card.addon.enable();
        }
    """)
    if len(fx.window_handles) != 1:
        fx.switch_to.window(addonsTabHandle)
        fx.close()
```

Comment: I was considering this, but since that addon requires configuration (entering a key) I wanted to evade complications and just use the precooked profile…

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I updated my answer and added a way to use existing profiles.

Comment: No, the same, the behaviour doesn't depend on how I pass the profile, via opts or via profile argument.

Comment: Updated my answer. Seems like this is a problem in geckodriver.

Comment: Oh! Probably that's magic I'm looking for! Will give it a try later today or tomorrow. Thank you!